Responsive svg in d3 best way
I am trying to create a responsive SVG. It should scale when the browser is resized. I am currently using the parent container as a reference and setting things to be a % value. I get some issues with margins and the text has to be in vw or vh units. I also find that for different parts of the svg, the text isn't consistent - the text on the y-axis ticks will be a different size to text elements in the SVG if they have the same defined size. Here is what I have tried:
                const div = d3.select("#bar");
        div.selectChild('svg').remove();
        DimensionService.getHTMLDimensions(div);
        const divDimensions = DimensionService.getHTMLDimensions(div);
        const width = divDimensions.width;
        const height = divDimensions.height;
        const margin = {
            top: 0.05 * height,
            right: 0.10 * width,
            bottom: 0.1 * height,
            left: 0.45 * width
        };

        const svg = div
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', '100%')
            .attr('height', '100%');

        const maxEntry = d3.max(this.entryCountPerCategory, (d) => d.entryCount) || 0;
        const x = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, maxEntry])
            .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
        svg.append('g')
            .attr("transform", `translate(${(margin.left) * 1.1}, ${height - margin.bottom * 2})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        svg.append('text')
            .attr('x', (width + margin.left) / 2)
            .attr('y', height - margin.bottom / 2)
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .style('font-size', `1.5vw`)
            .text('x-axis');

        // Define the y-axis scale
        const y = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, height - margin.bottom * 2.5])
            .domain(this.entryCountPerCategory.map((d) => d.dvcat || ''))
            .padding(0.1);

        // Append the y-axis to the SVG, applying the transform to the entire group
        const yAxisGroup = svg.append('g')
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left * 1.1}, ${margin.top})`)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        // Optional: Adjust the text style or additional transformation for labels
        yAxisGroup.selectAll('text')
            .style('font-size', '0.75vw');

        svg.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left / 6}, ${height / 2}) rotate(-90)`)
            .style("font-size", "3vh") // Adjust the font size as needed
            .text("y-axis");

        svg.append('text')
            .attr('x', (width + margin.left) / 2)
            .attr('y', margin.top)
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .style('font-size', `1.5vw`)
            .text('title');

// Append the y-axis to the SVG, applying the transform to the entire group
const yAxisGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left * 1.1}, ${margin.top})`)
.call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Optional: Adjust the text style or additional transformation for labels
yAxisGroup.selectAll('text')
.style('font-size', '0.75vw');

svg.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left/6}, ${height / 2}) rotate(-90)`)
  .style("font-size", "3vh") // Adjust the font size as needed
  .text("y-axis");

  svg.append('text')
  .attr('x', (width + margin.left) / 2)
  .attr('y', margin.top)
  .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('font-size', `1.5vw`)
  .text('title');

Dimension Service retrieves the dimensions of the container.
I have been researching viewBox but it does not seem to work how I want. I have changed my approach with this to do a predefined width and height for the SVG and its elements.
at scales proportionally. This works but it does not scale when the height changes, only when the width changes.
const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        const div = d3.select("#bar");
        div.selectChild('svg').remove();
        const width = 1000;
        const height = 400;
        console.log(width)
        console.log(height)

        const margin = {
            top: 0.05 * height,
            right: 0.10 * width,
            bottom: 0.1 * height,
            left: 0.45 * width
        };

        const svg = div
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

        const maxEntry = d3.max(this.entryCountPerCategory, (d) => d.entryCount) || 0;
        const x = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, maxEntry])
            .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
        svg.append('g')
            .attr("transform", `translate(${(margin.left) * 1.1}, ${height - margin.bottom * 2})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        svg.append('text')
            .attr('x', (width + margin.left) / 2)
            .attr('y', height - margin.bottom / 2)
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .style('font-size', `24px`)
            .text('x-axis');

        // Define the y-axis scale
        const y = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom * 2.5])
            .domain(this.entryCountPerCategory.map((d) => d.dvcat || ''))
            .padding(0.1);

        // Append the y-axis to the SVG, applying the transform to the entire group
        const yAxisGroup = svg.append('g')
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left * 1.1}, ${margin.top})`)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        // Optional: Adjust the text style or additional transformation for labels
        yAxisGroup.selectAll('text')
            .style('font-size', '12px');

        svg.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left / 6}, ${height / 2}) rotate(-90)`)
            .style("font-size", "24px") // Adjust the font size as needed
            .text("y-axis");


        svg.append('text')
            .attr('x', (width + margin.left) / 2)
            .attr('y', margin.top)
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .style('font-size', `24px`)
            .text('title');

Combining the two does not seem to work - it only renders half of my SVG.
